# can't connect with skype neither access skype web site

Tags: https, skype

I'm currently visiting Egypt and skype stopped working after a few days. It gives me "Skype home unavailable" and the status icon keeps spinning. I already searched the net for this issue and tried a few things which did not work. I also tried web skype and it the status icon shows green but messages don't go through anyway. I'm not asking about this general issue which seems to have many possible sources.

Now, while searching for this problem I came to realise that some web pages from skype web site are also not accessible, and I suspect it is either a HTTPS protocol configuration, or the Internet service is blocking skype.

For instance, this page:

https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10953/how-can-i-update-my-windows-firewall-settings-after-reinstalling-or-upgrading-skype

does not work in Firefox ("Secure Conection Failed") and in IE11 it only started working after after I actived SSL 2.0 and 3.0. Still, although skype-web opened once now I'm not even able to open it.

The address https://web.skype.com/ retuns "This page can’t be displayed" in IE11. And the button "Fix connection problems" finds nothing. After a few retries it seems to work out. Skype messages eventually eventually seem to get through but I can never do a live chat or a call or even a real phone call.

So, any idea why I can't access this and other skype pages? Is there some updated authentication protocol not well supported? Is there a way I can track it (I'm not a network specialist but maybe I can try something).

I found about blockage in Egypt: http://stepfeed.com/more-categories/big-news/egypt-blocks-popular-voip-apps-monitoring-facebook-skype/#.V0M9uVIiggQ

but I was able to use it when I arrived.

Comment: Quick google search reveals that egypt does/did block/monitor online voip and instant messaging services

Comment: strange, I was able to use skype for several days and the search I did only got me old blockages, not recently. Can you send a link?

Comment: Used the same ISP the whole time?

Comment: Yes, Etisalat. I use a USB stick. But maybe the blockage is selective or maybe the system can't block all the time.